# c++ passing 2d arrays to funcions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, 2d

I know my code isnt finished yet im not asking for it to be done. It's supposed to input food eaten by 3 monkeys over a week and other stuff. But I've hit a snag. It gives me an error(Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands) when i put the cin in the poundsEaten function. Am I not passing the array right is that why it isnt working? Thanks for any help

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Global Constants
const int NUM_MONKEYS = 3;
const int DAYS = 7;

//Prototypes
void poundsEaten(const double[][DAYS],int, int);
void averageEaten();
void least();
void most();

int main()
{
    //const int NUM_MONKEYS = 3;
    //const int DAYS = 7;
    double foodEaten[NUM_MONKEYS][DAYS]; //Array with 3 rows, 7 columns

    poundsEaten(foodEaten, NUM_MONKEYS, DAYS);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void poundsEaten(const double array[][DAYS], int rows, int cols)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < rows; index++)
    {
        for(int count = 0; count < DAYS; count++)
        {
            cout << "Pounds of food eaten on day " << (index + 1);
            cout << " by monkey " << (count + 1);
            cin >> array[index][count];
            // Here is where i get the error
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `array` as containing `const double`s. They're constant, so you can't write to them as you are trying to do with `cin >> array[index][count];`. Just change the parameter declaration to:

```
double array[][DAYS]
```

Perhaps you should think about when and why you should declare a variable as `const`.

As an aside to avoid later confusion, it's worth mentioning here that there's no such thing as array type parameters. The above parameter is actually transformed to:

```
double (*array)[DAYS]
```

However, your code is written appropriately to work with this (you passed the number of `row`s to the function).

Answer (score 0):

you declare:

```
const double array[][DAYS],
```

however, inside `poundsEaten` function, you are asking user to input information to fill in the `array`, which means the `array` is not const, therefore, error. Remove the `const` qualifier from the parameter such that the `array` can be changed by user input.

```
void poundsEaten(double array[][DAYS], int rows, int cols)
```

BTW: don't use `array` as variable name for an array, use some other names for good practice.
Meanwhile,`cols` is not used inside your `poundsEaten` function.